# Unable to show the latitude and longitude in the InfoWindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, infowindow

I have a java script function which I am using to display a marker on the selected position of the map and also show the latitude and longitude at the marker's location in a InfoWindow.

I could display the marker at any location but unable to show a InfoWindow with the coordinates.

This is the function:

```
function init()
{
 var mapoptions=
 {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.379064211298, 78.478946685791),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }
 map=new  google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_can"), mapoptions);
 var marker;
 google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event)
     {
        marker= new google.maps.Marker({position:event.latLng,map:map});
     });
 var iwindow= new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(event)
    {
       iwindow.setContent(event.latLng.lat()+","+event.latLng.lng());
       iwindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
```

Where am I wrong? Suggestions please.

Comment: Are you sure that `marker` in `iwindow.open(map,marker);` is available in the scope of the listener? I suggest you try creating a hidden marker object inside of the listener function and using that to setup the iwindow. Edit: Of course, the new hidden marker would make use of `event.latLng` to be setup correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you attach event to an empty marker object (it is unassigned at the moment when you invoke

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(event) { ... });
```

Try attaching click event to the marker after you create it, e.g.:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event)
 {
    marker= new google.maps.Marker({position:event.latLng,map:map});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(event)
    {
        iwindow.setContent(event.latLng.lat()+","+event.latLng.lng());
        iwindow.open(map,marker);
    });
 });
```

Comment: +1 This is correct. I came to the same conclusion. http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/582/

Comment: Oh yea I made a mess there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snipped code :

```
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout, id) {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: position,
                        map: map,
                        icon: image1,
                        title: "whatever!",
                        draggable: true,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.ROUTE
                    }));

                    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event)
                    {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[id], 'click', function (event)
                        {
                            infoWindow.setContent(event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng());
                            infoWindow.open(map, markers[id]);
                        });
                    });

                }, timeout);
            }
```